# Mostrar y esconder iconos en angular

Tags: angular

estoy intentando mostrar o esconder unos iconos en un template contenido en un componente dentro de la aplicación de angular en la que estoy trabajando ahora para aprender angular y estoy un poco sin ideas, intento que al darle al botón de "male" se muestre el icono correspondiente a la vez que se oculta del de "female" y viceversa, he intentado acceder a las clases a través del DOM con el fin de jugar con el atributo hidden y mostrar y ocultar los iconos pero angular no lo pone fácil en ese sentido.

este es el html del template:

```
<div class="input-row">

              <label>Gender:</label>
              <br>
              <div class="btn-group mr-3">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="changeGender()" value="M">Male <i class="fa fa-mars"></i></button>

                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="changeGender()" value="F">Female <i class="fa fa-venus"></i></button>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="selected-gender">

                <span class="Female" hidden><i class="fa fa-venus fa-2x"></i></span>
                <span class="Male" hidden><i class="fa fa-mars fa-2x"></i></span>

              </div>

            </div>
```

Y este el typeScript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { CharacterVariables } from "../CharacterVariables";

@Component({
  selector: 'AppCharacterData',
  templateUrl: './app.AppCharacterData.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.AppCharacterData.sass' ],
})
export class AppCharacterDataComponent {
  title = 'Character Data page';
  charVar: CharacterVariables;

  constructor(charVar: CharacterVariables) {
    this.charVar = charVar;
  }

  public changeName() {
    let t = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target);
    this.charVar.name = t.value;
  }

  public changeGender() {
    let t = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target);
    this.charVar.gender = t.value;
     if(t.value == 'M'){

     }
  }
}
```

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia es bienvenida, un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la directiva [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) de *Angular*.

`ngIf` habilita o deshabilita el renderizado de un elemento HTML en el DOM en función a una condición que se especifique.

En tu caso, mostrar el icono *male* si el género seleccionado es `M` y mostrar el icono *female* si se selecciona `F`.

```
<div class="selected-gender">

   <span class="Female" *ngIf="charVar.gender == 'F'"><i class="fa fa-venus fa-2x"></i></span>
   <span class="Male" *ngIf="charVar.gender == 'M'"><i class="fa fa-mars fa-2x"></i></span>

</div>
```

El DOM virtual de *Angular* va a renderizar o no de forma dinámica (y automática) en cuanto cambien las variables y las condiciones.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Buenas VRoxa, gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente el *ngIf ha ayudado, por lo menos los iconos ya no aparecen, sin embargo no parece reconocer charVar.gender y da un error "Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'span'", no estoy seguro si tiene que ver, pero las variables las tengo en un archivo aparte en un @injectable. Podría ser eso? las variables solo las reconoce si están entre {{*}}, pero el ngIf no parece llevarse muy bien con esto.

Comment: No tiene nada que ver. ¿Has importado `CommonModule` en tu módulo?

Comment: si, está importado en el app.module.ts, pero aun así

Comment: Ok, ya está solucionado, simplemente había olvidado mencionar el elemento en app.module, es un componente dentro de otro componente y se me había pasado, muchas gracias por la ayuda